# Class not found in simple spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and wrote a very simple Spark application in Scala as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._


object test2object {

def main(args: Array[String]) {
 val logFile = "src/data/sample.txt"
 val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Simple App", "/path/to/spark-0.9.1-incubating",
 List("target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar"))
 val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
 val numTHEs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("the")).count()
 println("Lines with the: %s".format(numTHEs))
}
}
```

I'm coding in Scala IDE and included the spark-assembly.jar into my code. I generate a jar file from my project and submit that to my local spark cluster using this command `spark-submit --class test2object --master local[2] ./file.jar` but I get this error message:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test2object.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:649)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

What is wrong here?

p.s. my source code is under the project root directory (project/test2object.scala)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use spark 0.9.1 before, but I believed the problem came from this line of code:

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Simple App", "/path/to/spark-0.9.1-incubating", List("target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar"))
```

If you change to this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple App")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

This will work.